# Detect if WiX Managed Bootstrapper Application requires elevation

Tags: wix, windows-installer, uac

I've had a look at this https://www.wrightfully.com/part-6-of-writing-your-own-net-based-installer-with-wix-a-note-about-uac/ but this doesn't work in my circumstance.

I have two applications using the same Managed BA, one requires elevation and the other requires it only on install not on major upgrade. Is there any way to detect these conditions, i.e. are there any bundle properties that examine the underlying install to see if UAC is required or not or does it not know until elevation is requested by the packages?

Comment: Can you explain how an installer would been elevation on install but not major upgrade?  I could see this for minor upgrade scenarios but that doesn't make sense for a major upgrade.

Comment: I install permanent C++ merge module on initial install.

Comment: Is your MSI per-user or per machine?

Comment: Per machine for C++ runtime, perUser for the other application MSI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deploy the C++ runtime private with your application or static link the libraries into your binaries.  Now you're installer will never require elevation.

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't actually answer the question if you can detect if an installation requires elevation or not

Comment: Sometimes the answer is to answer the question that isn't asked.  How can I simplify my design?